# Sorteio entre opções definidas pelo usuário

Tags: c++, random

Olá, estou criando um simulador de Rede de Petri (considerei um desafio, já que sou iniciante) e gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de criar um sorteio entre opções definidas pelo usuário. Eu gostaria de sortear entre, por exemplo, 0, 2, 3 e 5 (esses números são posições de um array). O array possui a quantidade de posições definidas pelo usuário (isso já foi providenciado), e o programa irá ler as posições que o usuário deseja. Preciso que o programa sorteie uma das posições definidas e incremente o valor na posição sorteada. Eu não consegui fazer isso com o rand() comum pois ele só sorteia entre uma faixa de números, e não entre opções. Existe essa possibilidade?

Comment: Tem como compartilhar sua tentativa?

Answer (score 1):

A ideia é sortear pela quantidade de elementos do seu vetor e não pelos números que lá estão. Imaginando que tem um vetor com `[45,3,40,12,2]` tem de sortear de `0` a `4`, que são as posições do vetor e não de `2` a `45` que seriam os números.

Se os números que quer sortear são casas de um array também não fará diferença. Construa um novo array com esses números (casas) e faça o sorteio dai. No seu caso poderia considerar como números disponíveis:

```
int disponiveis[] = {0,2,3,5};
```

E sortear sobre este array, e o resto da lógica se aplicaria de igual forma.

**Sorteio simples sem quantidade**

```
srand (time(NULL)); //inicializar a semente randomica

int nums[4] = {0 , 2, 3 ,5};
int posicaoSorteada = rand() % 4; //gerar um numero de 0 a 4

//mostrar o elemento na posição sorteada
std::cout<<"Elemento sorteado "<<nums[posicaoSorteada];
```

[Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/MM4xkQ)

Repare como o sorteio foi feito pelas posições e não pelos números em si.

---

**Sorteio com quantidade**

Se precisar de saber a quantidade de vezes que um elemento foi sorteado pode transformar o vetor num array de duas dimensões e cada vez que sorteia guarda a quantidade na segunda dimensão.

Desta forma é como se tivesse na primeira coluna o número e na segunda coluna a quantidade de vezes que já saiu.

```
srand (time(NULL));

//agora com duas dimensões, e a 2 dimensão começa a 0 para todos, que é a quantidade
int nums[4][2] = {{0,0} ,{2,0},{3,0},{5,0}};

int sorteios = 30; //sortear 30 elementos

while (sorteios-- > 0){
    int posicaoSorteada = rand() % 4;
    nums[posicaoSorteada][1]++; //aumenta a quantidade do numero sorteado, coluna 1
    std::cout<<"Elemento sorteado "<<nums[posicaoSorteada][0]<<" ja saiu "
    <<nums[posicaoSorteada][1]<<" vezes"<<endl;
}
```

[Veja este exemplo também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/MhNnGk)

Repare como neste ultimo exemplo `nums[..][0]` refere o número ao passo que `nums[..][1]` refere a quantidade.